# Using mobile-fu with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile

I am just starting out with RoR, and I'm having some problems. I'm using the Mobile-Fu plugin to load my application.mobile.haml file. The index page loads fine, but whenever I select another page, it loads the non-mobile haml file.

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :mobile

  before_filter :get_event, :except => [:index]
  before_filter :is_mobile

  def index
    @events = Event.all
    respond_with(@events)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@event)
  end

  private
  def is_mobile
    @mobile = is_mobile_device?
  end

  def get_event
    @event = params[:id].present? ? Event.find(params[:id]) : Event.new
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have correct mobile views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it by changing one my private functions to this:

```
 private
 def is_mobile
    request.format = :mobile if is_mobile_device?
 end
```

Comment: mobile_fu has a helper method called is_mobile_view? you can use instead of @mobile